# Modifying vertices x,y values to remove all value from 3rd decimal in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vertices, precision-scale

I want to check whether there is a way to update the vertices x, y value and remove all values from the 3rd decimal. I only want 2 decimals (no matter the 3rd decimal is 0 or 9, just remove it).

The original data and the desired data is like the following:

25642.882  38471.416 (need to change to 25642.88  38471.41)

25648.078  38446.104 (need to change to 25648.07  38446.10)

25655.240  38406.615 (need to change to 25655.24  38406.61)

Any advice?

Comment: how are you planning on using the values?

Comment: Hi TsvGis, actually I need to modify all the vertices value and export in a mdb file, thanks.

Comment: Are the x,y z values shown as attributes in the attribute table?

Comment: why not set the precision of the destination feature dataset to two decimals  ?

Answer (score 3):

I am sure there is a better way but this will work:

1. In the attribute table, create 3 new fields called x, y and z and
   make the field type "Double"
2. Right mouse click on the X field and calculate its geometry x coordinate
3. Right mouse click on the y field and calculate its geometry for the y coordinate
4. Right mouse click on the z field and calculate its geometry for the z coordinate
5. Select all records in the attribute table and then right click on its layer file and go: "Selection>Copy Records for Selected Features"
6. Open up Excel and paste in the selected attributes
7. In Excel, format the x,y,z cells to category of Number and set the decimal places to 2.
8. Save the Excel Table as .CSV
9. In Arcgis go: "File>Add data>Add XY data"
10. In the Add XY Data window, specify the .csv you created in point 8 and assign the x,y,z fields into the appropriate drop down windows. Set the coordinate system and then click OK.
11. The final output will be a layer with the required formatted numbers for the x,y and z.

Answer (score 3):

Field calculator expression, Python:

```
def truncate(f, n):
 s = '{}'.format(f)
 i, p, d = s.partition('.')
 return '.'.join([i, (d+'0'*n)[:n]])
```

To run on x, y and z fields, e.g.:

```
truncate( !POINT_X!,2)
```

Code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python modified slightly for field calculator

Second field calculator expression to run on Shape field

```
import arcpy
def PointMake(x, y,z):
 return arcpy.Point(x,y,z)
```

Call:

```
PointMake( !POINT_X!, !POINT_Y!, !POINT_Z!)
```